# How can i link wordpress post's title to pdf file download?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, post, hyperlink

Hi and i'm sorry for my english.

In the website that i'm building i want to provide a section where an user can download a pdf document direct from the post title link. I try to explain me better.

I want that my client can write posts (divided in many categories) with only a title and a pdf file attached.

In the front-end of the site i provide a page that loads the title from every post of a particular category and if an user click on these title, download the relative pdf file attached.

Is there a way to do this so I can skip the extra step of "click here to view" in my post? In other words i want to add a post, and when that post is clicked on i want it to download a PDF rather than actually linking to the post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The right code is:

```
<?php 
$categoria = get_cat_ID('mycategory');
$posts = get_posts('category='.$categoria);
foreach($posts as $post) { 
$content = $post->post_content; 
?>
<a href="<?php echo($content); ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a></br>
<?php } ?>
```

Or maybe this is another better solution:

```
//seleziono la categoria che voglio mostrare
$categoria = get_cat_ID('casi di studio');
//prendo i post solo di quella categoria
$posts = get_posts('category='.$categoria); 
//per ogni post ricavato vado a cercare se esiste un allegato
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
        ); 

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    //se l'allegato c'è entro nell'if
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            // Get the parent post ID
            $parent_id = $attachments->post_parent;
            // Get the parent post Title
            $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );
            echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, '' , false, false, $parent_title ); 
            ?>
            </br>
        <?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternately you could just use the "Page Links To" plugin for this purpose.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't want to use plugin.

Comment: I would just use a custom field for the PDF link (e.g. upload it to Wordpress and use the URL as the field value) and then in my template code simply replace `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` in the title anchor to `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdf-link', true); ?>`.